# Swift Alamofire JSON response has brackets

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to handle a JSON response using Alamofire from an Alamofire request:

`Alamofire.request(.POST, dbURL, parameters: ["username": username, "password": password]) .responseJSON { response in ... }`

I'm reading the response with

`let JSONResponse = response.result.value!`

The value of this returns

> ({ keyOne = 2; keyTwo = 4; keyThree = 2; keyFour = 6;})

And to get data from this,

`JSONResponse.valueForKey("exampleKey")`

The problem I get is that this doesn't return simple data, it returns this (the responses are all numbers, but I can't use integerForKey because of obvious reasons):

> (2)
>
> (4)
>
> (2)
>
> (6)

How can I get, read and/or save the data from this function without the brackets?
I tried brute force-removing the brackets using `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString()` but this is ugly and doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: What is the actual json response? Can you paste it here?

Comment: And adding to Pradeep's question, have you tried deserialising the JSON?

Comment: this is called Optional in swift.

Comment: deserialising the JSON didn't work properly. I added the complete JSON response.

Comment: Where are you seeing these parentheses appear? Is it when debugging, or printing to the console, or...? I'm wondering if you're just seeing these in the debugger/console as an indication that you're dealing with an unwrapped Optional.

Comment: ({ keyOne = 2; keyTwo = 4; keyThree = 2; keyFour = 6;}) is not valid JSON. Is this the correct json `{ "keyOne":2, "keyTwo":4, "keyThree":2, "keyFour":6 }`

Comment: Seeing as you are using a 3rd party library AlamoFire, I'd recommend using SwiftyJSON along with it, the two work really well together. Alamofire for getting JSON and SwiftyJSON will help you turn that JSON into objects really easy. Just something to think about.

Comment: @CraigOtis These parentheses appear in the complete response I get from my PHP file (json_encode($var)). Because they are in the response, they get stored in the NSUserDefaults and they get printed out when I try to.

Answer (score 0):

If your json is this `{ "keyOne":2, "keyTwo":4, "keyThree":2, "keyFour":6 }`
then this code should return the proper int values for you.

```
if let jsonURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sample", withExtension: "json")
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, jsonURL, parameters:nil) .responseJSON {
        response in
        if let JSONResponse = response.result.value as? [String:Int]
        {
            print(JSONResponse)
            if let val = JSONResponse["keyOne"] {
            print ("val = \(val)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```